# iframe pdf download (pop up) using python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pdf, iframe

I'm trying to download a pdf file embedded in "iframe" using python cm selenium. I manage to get to the part of opening the pdf pop up, but it doesn't download.

I tried every way to click this "Abrir" button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PxAG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39vLi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE4LN.png)